# Request dispatcher in while loop

Tags: java, servlets

My actual code :

```
String input = "ECE&&non teaching staffs.*";
try{
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data1.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if( Pattern.matches(in Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'put,strLine)){(.*?)'");
            Matcher mt = pattern.matcher(strLine);
        while (mt.find()) {
            String b=mt.group(1);
            request.setAttribute("a",a);
            String c=b.toString()+".*";
            FileInputStream fsstream = new FileInputStream("data1.txt");
            DataInputStream inn = new DataInputStream(fsstream);
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inn));
            String stringLine;
            while ((stringLine = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                if( Pattern.matches(c,stringLine)){
                    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#");
                    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(stringLine);
                    while (mat.find()) {
                        String g=mat.group(1);
                        request.setAttribute("a",a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

How can I use request dispatcher in a `servlet` to print some values using while loop like

```
while(...)
{
    String a="anything";
    request.setAttribute("a",a);

    while(...)
    {
        String b="anything else";
        request.setAttribute("a",a);
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response); 
}
```

In this case it gives only one value and `while` works only once
Where exactly to put the request dispatcher so that the `while` loop works and whether to use `forward(...)` or not ? please help !

Comment: what is the condition of while to continue?

Comment: Actually i have just given a demo code, in my actual code the while loop contains condition of FileRead, in that i am reading values from the text file like----- while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {..} what so ever the request dispatcher is creating the problem why does the while not work ?

Comment: From you post it seems there might be a problem with the condition in while loop. And now for your comment it seems you are trying to read a text file. Does your text file contains only one line?

Comment: I have added my actual code, my txt file contains more than 1 line and the line i m doing Pattern-match with in my txt file is---- ECE&&non teaching staffs( ' Abc ' | ' Def ' ) so putting dispatcher outside while results only Def and putting dispatcher just after--request.setAttribute("a",a); it results Abc. But i want it to result both Abc and Def

Comment: Please  help, i m trying a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Using .forward it totally takes away the control of the servlet and forwards it to another jsp page but we can use .include it stays in the current servlet only just including the required jsp page wherever required.